# How to post a CSV file to a spring rest endpoint using curl

Tags: java, spring, rest, curl

I'm trying to create a rest endpoint with java spring that accepts a csv file.

My Controller looks like this:

Interface:

```
package my.company.my.project.trms.controller;

import my.company.my.project.trms.controller.common.ControllerUrls.INBOX.CSV;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(CSV.BASE)
public interface CsvController {

  @PostMapping(produces = "text/csv", consumes = "text/csv")
  public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody MultipartFile file);
}
```

*CSV.BASE is a static final String holding my endpoint url

Implementation:

```
package my.company.my.project.trms.controller;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class CsvControllerImpl implements CsvController {

  @Override
  public ResponseEntity create(MultipartFile file) {
    String message = "";
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(message);
  }
}
```

I want to test this endpoint with the folowing sh script executet on a windows pc using git bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8791/api/public/v1/inboxes/csv" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: text/csv" --data-binary @/c/Users/Schilling/Desktop/Test.csv
```

When I execute the script my controller Method is called. However, setting a breakpoint shows me that the parameter "file" is always null.

I suspect there is something worng with the syntax of the file Path in the curl script, therefore I tried several things including absolute and relative paths.
Of cause the error could also originate from my controller class.

EDIT:

Adding the -vv option to the curl call resulted in this output:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == '192.168.99.100'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8791...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8791 (#0)
> POST /api/public/v1/inboxes/csv HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8791
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/csv
> Content-Length: 2036
> Expect: 100-continue
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 100
} [2036 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
100  2036    0     0  100  2036      0    221  0:00:09  0:00:09 --:--:--     0* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Type: text/csv;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 15 Oct 2021 12:37:43 GMT
<
100  2036    0     0  100  2036      0    203  0:00:10  0:00:09  0:00:01     0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: what does -VV show?

Comment: @codebrane thanks for the hint, I did not know the existence of this curl option. Pleas see the edited post above.

Comment: curl is sending Content-Type: text/csv does your endpoint support that content-type?

Comment: @codebrane It should, at least I added consumes = "text/csv" to the mapping annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work as it needs to be:
Content-Type: multipart/form-data according to the code.

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -vv -F upload=@/c/Users/Schilling/Desktop/Test.csv "http://localhost:8791/api/public/v1/inboxes/csv"
```

Comment: This one returnes a 415 response code. I added -H "Content-Type: text/csv" to it, after that the result was the same as before: file = null

Comment: I also tried -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"

Comment: ah, I forgot to change the parameter name. `curl -vv -F file=@/c/Users/Schilling/Desktop/Test.csv "http://localhost:8791/api/public/v1/inboxes/primedex-csv" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"` worked after changing consumes to "multipart/form-data" in the controller.